# Remote Desktop Printer Redirection: Driver not found

Tags: remote-desktop, printing

I have a problem getting printer redirection to work over a remote desktop connection, with one specific printer only. It is an EPSON TM-U220A, a dot matrix receipt printer which is connected via serial port. Both client and "server" are Windows 7 Professional x64.

- The printer works locally.
- Redirection of a HP Laserjet P1102 printer connected to the same client works fine.
- On the remote side, a TerminalServicesPrinters error 1111 is logged, claiming that it cannot find the required driver "EPSON TM-U220 ReceiptE4".
- On both client and server, a driver named exactly like this is installed (including the weird "E4" at the end, verified by looking a the print server properties).

I have set up quite a number of different printers for remote desktop use, in all cases the main problem was installing exactly the same printer driver on both client and server. But in this case, I triple checked and I am 100% sure that the driver name matches, architecture matches, OS matches - I have no idea what the problem is.

I could as well try redirecting the serial port instead, but I'd really like to find a solution to this one. EPSON won't help, as long as the printer is working locally it's not their problem. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Some driver are just not ready for terminal services (remote desktop services now) .

There is compatibility list on printer driver support site. Sometime another driver for another printer model work in remote desktop but you can have weird problems like bad character or black images etc.

No real solution other then get a 100% remote desktop ready printer and driver :)

EDIT : or try this :  epson universal printer driver

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any printer specific functions, many receipt printers can be used with Generic/Text-Only drivers. You may try using this driver.

If you use Generic/Text-Only in combination with printer redirection, make sure to disable EasyPrint for these clients - otherwise it won't work. [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cd8792cb-e826-4f35-bdaf-c5b29ca58ca8/easyprint-and-generic-text-only?forum=windowsserver2008r2rds) is a discussion about this topic.

The important GPO setting for this is:

> Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services (Remote Desktop Services) \Terminal Server (Session Host) \ Printer Redirection \ Use Terminal Services (RDS) Easy Print printer driver first: **Disabled**

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
1) Enable port sharing on RDP->Local Resources->More...
2) Add COM1 port to your local printer (Printer Properties->Ports, right click)
3) Install printer as local, but set port to TS001.

Printing will throw an error, but will work anyway.